# Jupyter Notebook .ipynb (in Visual Studio) does not print after successfully reading a large .mdb file

Tags: python, ms-access, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

After many attempts, I have successfully read a large `.mdb` file (5 million rows and 12 columns). Please see code below:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:/Users/..../Data.mdb')
curs = conn.cursor()

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Data;'# insert your query here
curs.execute(SQL)

rows = curs.fetchall()

curs.close()
conn.close()
```

I have two problems:

(1) I am not able to print `rows` or anything for that matter and i keep getting a visual studio pop-up saying that `the window cannot open.`   This most likely related to memory issue.

(2) In the rare occasion where i was able to print, I was not able to know which dtype `rows` is. The step is important as I would like to save rows into `.parquet file` .

```
print(rows.dtype)
```

gives an error as follows:  `this object has no attribute 'dtype'`

Can someone comment on this please?

Some additional clarifications. I tried to save `rows` into a csv file but i get the following error. Hence, the need to save it into `.parquet` file

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(open('mytable.csv', 'w'), lineterminator='\n')

for row in rows:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [89], line 5
      2 csv_writer = csv.writer(open('mytable.csv', 'w'), lineterminator='\n')
      4 for row in rows:
----> 5     csv_writer.writerow(row)
File C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1252.py:19, in IncrementalEncoder.encode(self, input, final)
     18 def encode(self, input, final=False):
---> 19     return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 15-17: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: The actual problem is loading 5M rows in memory. Nobody can read 5M scrolling rows. If you want to *export* the database data to Parquet or CSV you should avoid reading any more data than necessary. Instead of calling `fetchall` you can iterate the rows and write each one to the CSV file for example.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Thank you for your response. Can 5M rows be stored in a CSV?  In any case, i have just done my first attempt writing the database into a csv using `csv_writer = csv.writer(open('mytable.csv',  'w', encoding="utf-8"), lineterminator='\n')`  then i iterate over each row but the issue is that the data is not written properly. I think iam using the wrong encoding

Comment: What version is the .mdb file? If you are unsure then you could use [accdb_mdb_header_info](https://github.com/gordthompson/accdb_mdb_header_info) to check it.

Comment: A CSV is nothing more than a text file with one row per line. Nothing more. You can store as much text as you want. The problem you posted means there's a problem with the text. Add error handling and print the line where the error occurs. Most likely, the Access database contains non-Unicode text in a codepage that doesn't match your locale

Comment: @GordThompson  it is version 2002 -2003

Comment: Glad to see you got through your initial driver/connection string issues. A CSV can definitely hold 5M records. When opening the file for  `csv.writer` specify the character encoding to UTF-8 like `csv.writer(open('output_file_name', 'w',  encoding='utf-8'), lineterminator='\n')` It's not guaranteed to fix the issue, but it's a good first step and you may get lucky. Basically there may be some unicode in your accessDB that is not nicely re-encoding to the default encoding of the file in python.

Comment: Can you read that database using Access itself? Are there any missing characters in the text? Eg any `?` or `�` characters?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   Yes I can read the data using Access. The raw data contains textual data (in French and Arabic), characters (slash and backslah), numeric values (floats), Date (year-month-day) and some floats mixed with characters in between like 1000/T/46/ or T65/68/89

Comment: This encoding gives better result  `utf-8-sig`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos re: "Nobody can read 5M scrolling rows." - I just did. After doing `df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM FiveMillionRows", engine)`, `df.shape` returns `(5000000, 5)`. It took a few minutes, but it wasn't impossible. (Unless you meant something specific by "scrolling" rows.)

Comment: I lost the information on column headers when iterating through `rows`. Can I somehow retrieve those headers in the process?

Comment: @GordThompson I meant it literally. I'm sure you've encountered the same problem eg with web sites that try to display thousands of rows in a table when you can only read 20-50 of them at a time. The solution is to *not* print all those rows, only print what you need

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Oh, okay. That's what you meant by "scrolling rows". Got it.

Comment: You should be able to get the column names using `list(col[0] for col in curs.description)`

Comment: @GordThompson  where would your line fit? I guess it is during the execution of SQL but where please. Thank you

Comment: After you do `Cursor.execute()`, [Cursor.description](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#description) contains information about the result set (if any).

Comment: @GordThompson  Thank you. The headers are extracted as you said but when I check the csv file they are not written in it. Somehow i am losing the information in between. Can you clarify  please?  Sorry you ll have to baby spoon me :).

Comment: I guess you'll need to write a line with the names out to the CSV file before iterating through the data rows and writing them out.